# Is it ok to give my cat tuna flavored cat food?

Tags: cats, diet

My cat only likes wet cat food that is tuna flavored. I switched to chicken flavored, as the vet said that tuna-based food is not good because this fish itself contains mercury.

He turns his nose up at the chicken flavored and cries until I open a tuna one. He currently eats about 1/2 cup of dry cat food (turkey flavored, IKR) each day as well as one or two 3 oz. (85 g) cans.

Is it truly harmful for cats to eat tuna flavored cat food, or should I keep trying with the chicken flavored cat food?

Comment: a cat needs a balanced diet,several types of food is needed but cats can be mighty stubborn when it comes to food so you have to experiment until you find something your cat likes.my cat only wants her food if it is in gravy not the paste type.and only one type of dryfood(it is complete so it is ok).there are several similar questions to yours on this site,read some of them maby you can use some of their answers to solve your problems.

Comment: @trondhansen Try to avoid answering the question in the comments section. If you've got a whole answer, then please add it as an answer below so it can be voted on.

Comment: @Henders will do,i did not see my comment as an answer .

Comment: @D.Moore I have had a problem with my cat not liking the usual wet cat food and especially hates most fish. I have been buying my cat this for the last few years and it's been gobbled up every time. https://www.fancyfeast.com/gourmet-cat-food/wet-cat-food/purely

Answer (score 9):

### Concern for mercury?

In your concern for mercury contents, this depends on the food company itself. The veterinary line of cat food tests ALL their food for heavy metals, toxins, contamination etc. before shipping out for consumption so it is safe to feed. However you need to do your due diligence and contact the company that produces the food you feed to your cat and ask them what kind of testing to they do.

There have been a few studies for [fish-based canned diets causing hyperthyroidism](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10997155), however I wouldn't rush to throw out all of his food in a panic.

### Poultry or Rabbit

If you aim for what a cat would eat "in the wild" go for rabbit-based or poultry-based diets. Transitioning should be slow, mix old food with the new food and gradually increase new food and reduce old food over a span of 7 days.

Unlike dogs, a cat **WILL** starve itself if he does not like the food - try a few different brands and flavors and see what your cat will like best. If he likes the turkey dry you can try to find the canned version of that brand of dry food.

Keep in mind that your cat may have a preference of chunks and gravy vs paté or prefer to have it warmed up before serving.

Comment: To add a bit on how to get your cat eating other food - mix it with his preferred kind, reducing the ratio of tuna v. new food each time.